# Get the number of elements returned by a CDSView in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Given the following MRE, is it possible to access or print the number of elements resulting from the application of the `CDSView` filter on the `ColumnDataSource` in Bokeh? In this simple case, I'd like to get the information that 3 rows are returned and, if possible, access the index of `ColumnDataSource.data` of the filtered rows.

```py
from bokeh.models import BooleanFilter, CDSView, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
booleansX = [True if x_val < 5 else False for x_val in source.data['x']]
booleansY = [True if y_val > 1 else False for y_val in source.data['y']]
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[BooleanFilter(booleansX), BooleanFilter(booleansY)])

p_filtered = figure(height=300, width=300)
p_filtered.circle(x="x", y="y", size=10, source=source, view=view)

show(p_filtered)
```

Note that this MRE is not the actual real data, I am just hoping to get this insight to debug a code using much larger CDS.